# How to check size of a folder in dsefs

Tags: cassandra

what is the command to check the size of the folder in `dsefs`?

i tried `df -h` it's not giving me size of a particular folder, it gives me size of the whole filesystem on all the nodes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get the size of each folder.

```
du -sh *
```

Example:

```
$ du -sh *
124K    bin
91M     clients
101M    demos
4.0K    ds_branch.txt
4.0K    ds_timestamp.txt
4.0K    ds_version.txt
7.4M    javadoc
8.2M    lib
412K    licenses
28K     LICENSE.txt
4.0K    README.md
800M    resources
100K    tools
```